# Calculate date & time difference between two cells (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS)

Tags: date, time, difference

[image: Data Sample]

I am trying to find the difference in datetime between two cells from an imported data file.

I cannot seem to find the correct formula with the formatting.

**DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS**

Is there anything I can do to help calculate without getting a #VALUE error? Attached below is a sample - the imported files often contain hundreds of entries.

Comment: Do you wants to do in Excel sheet ?

Comment: Yes, I would be creating a new column in excel to calculate the difference and highlight any discrepancies ("Difference" Column)

Comment: You want result in which format ?

Comment: Same format if possible - DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS

Comment: You can get difference in days, hour,min,sec.

Comment: I have just post an answer let me know if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Days, Months, Year, Hours and Minutes as difference between two dates. DD/MM/YYYY itself is a date format. You get can get datetime difference with:

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")&" years, "&DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")&" days, "&HOUR(B2-A2)&" hours, "&MINUTE(B2-A2)&" minutes and "&SECOND(B2-A2)&" seconds"
```

Comment: Thanks Damini. However I'm still getting an #VALUE error message when using the above formula. I've adjusted A1/B1 to A2/B2 values and have tried adjusting cell format from "General" "Date" and "Custom"

Comment: I have updated answer. Is that working after?

Comment: Nope, still not working (#VALUE) error

Comment: If you change the format of date to DD.MM.YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY and then try it please.

Answer (score 0):

As You have DD.MM.YYYY format,

```
=DATEDIF(SUBSTITUTE( A2,".","/"), SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/"),"y")&" years, "&DATEDIF(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/"),SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/"),"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIF(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/"),SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/"),"md")&" days, "&HOUR(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/") -SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/") )&" hours, "&MINUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/") -SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/") )&" minutes and "&SECOND(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/") -SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/") )&" seconds"
```